# Should I reinstall each module again if I install a new vesion of Python?

Tags: python, macos, python-module

I just installed Python 3.6 and run terminal, tried to `import` any of the modules I already installed in 3.5 (rsa, matplotlib, enchant, ...) and it returned:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_name'
```

However, they still work when I run Python 3.5. What should I do?

Comment: No, they're not going to happen automatically, either reinstall them or (copy-paste the site package folder)-don't recommend doing this

Answer (score 3):

If you install a different Python version you will **not** have the modules you did already install for your old version.

**Each Python version you install has its own working directory, and its own modules**. Modules installed for a certain version of Python, in general, cannot be used by other versions, older or newer. This is because Python modules often need precompiled files and version-specific features to work on a certain version of Python. For example, you cannot use a module for Python 2.7 on Python 3.6, since that a lot of stuff changed from version 2 to 3.

This means that **you will have to re-install any module you need on the new version of Python** again, which can easily be done [using PIP](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel) running `pythonX.Y`, where `X.Y` is the version number, like this:

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.6 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.6
```

---

Note also that copying the old site-package folder is **not** the same thing as reinstalling the modules, and should never be done.

Comment: might be useful to OP to explain "why", notably that while there are a lot of pure python sources which _will_ work correctly on both versions, there are also binary (C, etc.) modules which contain version specific compiled code (feel free to steal this, and edit it in :D)

Comment: `venv` comes as a command with post 3.5 pythons to manage per-project and per-python-version module dependencies. Probably worth a mention/brief summary. https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

in terminal or cmd type

```
pip install module_name
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.